# How to get the Selected INDEX of a dropdown list from a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Say I have

```
  <select id="year" name="year">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select>
```

In a form that I pass to my servlet. How can I get the selected INDEX of the list? I have tried looking online but all I can see are answers on how to get the VALUE.

I want the index, because I want to be able to save and load the parameters of a form, but I have dynamically created select lists with values that change when other values in the form change. So simply getting the current index to reload the form would be a lot simpler.

I need to use a servlet because I want to be able to save and load this data from a file, and I don't believe you can locally save files using only javascript. I know I can LOAD using only javascript though, but the problem lies in the saving for now.

I know you can get the selected value of the list by doing something like

```
request.getParameter("year");
```

But I've found no way so far of getting the selected index.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the selected INDEX of the list?

You can't - all that gets sent to the server when you submit the form is the value of the selected option (e.g. `year=2009`).

You'd have to add some client-side JavaScript to populate a hidden field in the form with the selected index whenever the selection changes.

Comment: Ahh, well that explains why I couldn't find anything on the subject! I guess I'll follow your advice and set up hidden fields then, thank you for the suggestion and quick answer!